# In nested Excel VBA For...Next loop, parent Next cannot find its For

Tags: vba

```
For j = 0 to SpreadCount
    If TypeName(ChainsDC(j,0) = "String" 'testing for an error
        Goto EndLoop
    Else:
        For i = 0 to RscSct
            ...do amazing things here (no loops)
        Next i
EndLoop:
Next j '<<<PROBLEM
```

Compiler complains Next j (line 9) is a "Next without For".

Comment: The VBA editor doesn't indent automatically. Else, you would see your "Next j" line on the same level as the "Next i", hence telling you the problem is with the missing "End if", like @PowerUser said in his answer.

Comment: This code has at least four syntax errors in it. At this point, it would probably help to read the VBA help file for each and all of the keywords you use.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your IF statement is the problem.  You need to add both a **Then** and a **End If**:

```
For j = 0 to SpreadCount
    If TypeName(ChainsDC(j,0) = "String" **Then**
        Goto EndLoop
    Else:
        For i = 0 to RscSct
            ...do amazing things here (no loops)
        Next i
    **End If**
EndLoop:
Next j '<<<PROBLEM
```

**Edit**
Your Typename is also missing a close parenthesis.

Comment: +1 I reckon the goto could be avoided with very little effort on the part of @MonteCarloGenerator

Comment: Actually, you could replace the goto by *nothing* and get the same effect!

Comment: @PowerUser: you should remove the `:` after `Else`.

Comment: There's a lot more wrong with the code then just the Then and End If :)

Answer (score 3):

```
For j = 0 to SpreadCount
    If TypeName(ChainsDC(j,0)) <> "String" Then
        For i = 0 to RscSct
            ...do amazing things here (no loops)
        Next i
    End If
Next j
```

As Remou pointed out, you should get rid of the Goto and test what you want to test, namely that it's not a string.

You should generally never have a colon after else unless there's another executable piece of code on that line.  And even then...

Answer (score 3):

There are several things wrong with your code and logic.

```
For j = 0 to SpreadCount
    If TypeName(ChainsDC(j,0) = "String" 'testing for an error
        Goto EndLoop
    Else:
        For i = 0 to RscSct
            ...do amazing things here (no loops)
        Next i
EndLoop:
Next j '<<<PROBLEM
```

The major issue is the logic - if you only care if the TypeName is not a string, check for that. There is no need to add the else statement, let alone a GoTo. As it's often said:

> A GoTo statement can often indicate an opportunity to fix the logic in
>   your code

One thing that helps is to concentrate on what you **want** to do, not what you **don't want** to do. Writing the expected/desired path first, then adding in side cases after (if needed) is good practice.

Other areas to fix:

- In line 2, you are missing a )
- In line 2,  take out the comment. Code is/should be self-explanatory.
- You should reverse i and j. Someone reading the code will assume i comes first.
- In line 4, you should remove the ":"

Here is the code cleaned up:

```
For i = 0 To SpreadCount
    If TypeName(ChainsDC(i, 0)) <> "String" Then
        For j = 0 To RscSct
            '...do amazing things here
        Next
    End If
Next
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `Else:` may be the problem, as well as the missing `End If`.

Comment: What's the problem you're seeing with it?

Comment: It's a label rather than an `Else`.

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo as I was copying into StackOverflow

Comment: Why don't you copy-paste the actual problem code into your question. That'd solve a lot of WTFs for people trying to answer.